# Select the last record on opening the ms access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a query as datasource. I want to go to the last record of the datasource automatically when the form is opened/loaded.

Any ideas on how I can do this using VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following:

```
Me.Recordset.MoveLast
```

Note that Access features control wizards for the button, and one option in that wizard is Record Navigation -> Go to last record. This generates an embedded macro, and not VBA.

Comment: The `Form_Load` event

Answer (score 3):

```
docmd.gotorecord acDataForm, "FormName", acLast
```

You could also play a trick and sort the records in reverse order. That might be something to think about.

Answer (score 2):

This one also worked for me :

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
```